# Issue while converting geoJson LineString data to ShapeFile `mapbox,shp-write`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, geojson, shapefile

I am using `mapbox/shp-write` library to convert my `GeoJson` format data to `ShapeFile` format.
Its all good and working fine if I try to convert my `Point` geometry FeatureData with geoJson properties.
But When I try to convert my `LineString` or `MultiLineString` geometry FeatureData then the array of featureData is treated as one single Line.
To be more precise when i try to convert my `LineString` featureData it gives only single property for all `LineString` data.
All featureData is treated as one single Line in shp zip.

For `Point` its working completely fine but not for `LineString`.

```
 var data = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: [{
                        type: "Feature",
                        geometry: {
                                type: "LineString",
                                coordinates: [[87.89027149215705, 26.646644114467723]
                                    , [87.89027202629471, 26.646642901566803]
                                    , [87.89030041505761, 26.646379725809183]
                                    , [87.8903994813448, 26.64593646446885]]
                            },
                            properties: {
                                "Class of Pipe": "6kgf",
                                "Condition": "Good",
                                "Diameter(mm)": "90"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "Feature",
                            geometry: {
                                type: "LineString",
                                coordinates: [[87.89039913077795, 26.645936083650973]
                                    , [87.89042436220545, 26.64543874910249]
                                    , [87.89046486856593, 26.6448668401776]
                                    , [87.89047787140778, 26.644522607334913]]
                            },
                            properties: {
                                "Class of Pipe": "8kgf",
                                "Condition": "Very Good",
                                "Diameter(mm)": "100"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "Feature",
                            geometry: {
                                type: "LineString",
                                coordinates: [[87.8906905, 26.642682]
                                    , [87.89094136016627, 26.641126787409135]
                                    , [87.89109621978956, 26.64070146502989]
                                    , [87.8912139, 26.6403716]]
                            },
                            properties: {
                                "Class of Pipe": "10kgf",
                                "Condition": "Very very Good",
                                "Diameter(mm)": "80"
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    }

  const options = {
                   folder: "my_internal_shapes_folder",
                        filename: "myFileName" + "-" + "Shp",
                        outputType: "blob",
                        compression: "DEFLATE",
                        types: {
                            point: "pointName",
                            polygon: "polygonName",
                            polyline: "polylineName"
                        },
                    };

shpwrite.download(data,options)
```

From my side I try what i could.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `... I try to convert my LineString or MultiLineString geometry` how are you trying this?

Comment: I am passing my `featureCollection` object which contains array of features as geoJson format .
updatedObj contains `featureCollection` Object

var shpwrite = require("@mapbox/shp-write");

shpwrite.download(updatedObj,options)

Comment: I mean in code, not as a general concept

Comment: Please post a [mre].